# How to unit test if an interceptor is registered within the DI?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have my startup like this:

```
builder.Services.AddGrpc(options =>
    {
        options.Interceptors.Add<ExceptionGrpcInterceptor>(); // << how to test if this is there
    });
```

Now I want to test if my application has this interceptor registered within the DI.

How to do that?

Comment: I think that unit tests should cover only your own code and in this case you want to ensure that something is done when you call `Add` method which is part of the framework/library. There might or might not be an opportunity to verify that this interceptor is added but this should be done in that frameworks tests, not in your code. You could check if this interceptor triggers with integration tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get options object from DI container

```
using ConsoleApp1;
using Grpc.AspNetCore.Server;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddGrpc(options =>
{
    options.Interceptors.Add<ExceptionGrpcInterceptor>();
});

IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

var options = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<GrpcServiceOptions>>();

bool hasInterceptor = options.Value.Interceptors.Any(x => x.Type == typeof(ExceptionGrpcInterceptor));

Console.ReadKey();
```